# mapping some images with out key and value pair in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a data like this

```
    const data = ["https://via.placeholder.com/60x60", 
"https://via.placeholder.com/60x60", 
"https://via.placeholder.com/60x60", 
"https://via.placeholder.com/60x60"];
```

not the pair of key and value.
I want to make it by mapping like,

```
<div> 
  <img src={} />
  <img src={} />
  <img src={} />
  <img src={} />
<div>
```

so coded

```
<div className="App">
      {data.map((item) => {
        <img src={item}/>
      })}
    </div>
```

but it does not work.
can any one help me?

Comment: Does not work is not specifying your problem , What You are getting in response ?

Comment: You need to use `return`. So `return <img src={item}/>`

Comment: i asked what format i wanted to make above the code

Comment: you mean return like <div className="App">
      {data.map((item) => {
        return <img src={item}/>
      })}
    </div>

Comment: yes, that is what i mean. The `map` callback must return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Without Scope

```
     <div className="App">
        {data.map((item, key) => (
          <img src={item} key={key} />
        ))}
      </div>
```

With Scope

```
       <div className="App">
        {data.map((item, key) => {
          return <img src={item} key={key} />;
        })}
      </div>
```